# Data grouping for 10 seconds. PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

It is necessary to find the average number of processed messages by the subscriber in 10 seconds within an hour. PLSQL
There are columns: subscriber, date ('dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm.ss') and messages, they are related (each message has its own time and the subscriber who processed it).

the idea was this:

```
SELECT subscriber, HH24, AVG(CNT) FROM (
SELECT subscriber,
trunc(date, 'HH24') HH24,
trunc(date - INTERVAL '10' SECOND) SS,
count(messages) CNT
FROM tables
where date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY subscriber,
trunc(date, 'HH24'),
trunc(date - INTERVAL '10' SECOND)
order by subscriber)
GROUP BY subscriber, HH24
```

Expected Result:

```
subscriber          HH24          CNT   
subscriber 1   01.01.01 21:00:00  8,88
subscriber 1   01.01.01 22:00:00  7,88
subscriber 2   01.01.01 21:00:00  6,66
subscriber 3   01.01.01 22:00:00  5,54
```

My query produces something like the following:

```
subscriber         HH24          CNT
subscriber 1  01.01.01 21:00:00  400
subscriber 1  01.01.01 22:00:00  500
subscriber 2  01.01.01 21:00:00  300
subscriber 3  01.01.01 22:00:00  500
```

Most likely my request does not group the data for 10 seconds, tell me where I made a mistake? Thank!

Comment: Your outer query groups only by subscriber and HH24, which gets rid of the `trunc(date - INTERVAL '10' SECOND)` you added in the inner query.

Comment: still not working :(
and the result should be only three columns

`subscriber 1 01.01.15 23:00:00 01.01.15 00:00:00 650`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explained poorly, but the problem was solved as follows:

```
SELECT subscriber, HH24, AVG(cnt / 3600) * 100 / 10 cnt
```

AVG - average value, CNT / 3600 - divide by the number of seconds per hour, * 100 - translate in percent, / 10 - we get the answer for 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
select subscriber, ss, count(сообщения) cnt from (
select subscriber,
       trunc(date) + (floor((date-trunc(date))*24*60*60/10)*10)/24/60/60 as ss, 
       сообщения
from tables
where date is not null)
group by subscriber, ss;
```

I'd better explain the big expression:

```
(date-trunc(date))*24*60*60  -- Time expressed as number of seconds since midnight (T1)
(floor(T1/10)*10)            -- ... rounded down to nearest 10 seconds (T2)
T2/24/60/60                  -- ... converted to fraction of a day (T3)
trunc(date)+T3               -- ... added back on to date
```

Comment: I understood the logic, thanks!
But I need the average number of messages that are processed in 10 seconds, within an hour.

I think ~
`SELECT subscriber, HH24, AVG(messages) FROM (
SELECT subscriber,
trunc(date, 'HH24') HH24,
trunc(date)+ (floor((date-trunc(date))*24*60*60/10)*10)/24/60/60 SS,
count(messages) `

but this request also returns incorrect values

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you are looking for. For this kind of task I use this generic function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MakeInterval(ts IN TIMESTAMP, roundInterval IN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND) RETURN TIMESTAMP DETERMINISTIC IS
    denom INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' HOUR THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(HOUR FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(24, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts) + TRUNC(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' HOUR;
    ELSIF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' MINUTE THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'hh') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE;
    ELSE
        denom := EXTRACT(SECOND FROM roundInterval);                
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'mi') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' SECOND;
    END IF;
END MakeInterval;
```

Then you can use it simple as `MakeInterval("date", INTERVAL '10' SECOND)`

However, maybe you are looking for [windowing_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#i97640), for example

```
AVG(CNT) OVER (PARTITION BY subscriber ORDER BY "date" RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT_ROW AND INTERVAL '10' SECOND FOLLOWING)
```